# Problem while printing a maximum value obtained from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, max, sql

I am trying to find the MAX number from a database field,The query below returns me the maximum value if i run it in `SQL Enterprise Manager` but i am not able to print the value in numbwe. Please help me to print the MAX value obtained from the database.

```
    SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=hcgoa;User Id=sa;Password=;");
    SqlCommand MyCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX([no]) AS Expr1 FROM jmain", MyConnection);
    MyConnection.Open();
    SqlDataReader myReader = MyCmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (myReader.Read())

    {
        string numbwe = myReader["no"].ToString();
        Response.Write("Max no. is : " + numbwe); 
    }
```

Comment: Instead of creating a reader to read only one value, you could use ExecuteScalar.

Comment: @Johann Blais: +1 exactly for mentioning ExecuteScalar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Expr1` as the key, not `no`.

That's because you're doing:

```
SqlCommand MyCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX([no]) AS Expr1 ...
```

(note the `AS` clause) so the column is named `Expr1`. Hence:

```
string numbwe = myReader["Expr1"].ToString();
```

should do it.

Although, in fairness to those who come after you, `Expr1` is not a very descriptive identifier. Consider the possibility of changing it to something like `MaxNum` (both in the `select` and the key, of course).

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [ExecuteScalar()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) instead if you are going to return a single value.

> MSDN: Use the ExecuteScalar method to
>   retrieve a single value (for example,
>   an aggregate value) from a database.
>   This requires less code than using the
>   ExecuteReader method, and then
>   performing the operations that you
>   need to generate the single value
>   using the data returned by a
>   SqlDataReader.

Comment: +1 for ExecuteScalar() because, that is exactly what he should be using.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to print the value of a column that doesn't exist in the query result.  Your query returns a column named Expr1, not a column named "no"

Change

```
string numbwe = myReader["no"].ToString();
```

to

```
string numbwe = myReader["Expr1"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

should be `string numbwe = myReader["Expr1"].ToString();`

as you are specifying your column name in sql statement Expr1

```
SELECT MAX([no]) AS Expr1
```